# How to make round up to count up the even decimal value (example., if it is 2.25 it should round up to 2.3 not 2.2)

Tags: java, format, double, rounding

I am trying to format double value to one decimal point using below code but it produces two different rounding values.

```
 double d1= 4.55;
 double d2= 17.85;
 DecimalFormat oneDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
 System.out.println(oneDForm.format(d1));
 System.out.println(oneDForm.format(d2));
```

Output:
4.6
17.8 (Expecting 17.9)

But what i wanted roundup by counting up for even decimal `17.85` to `17.9`, how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have full code ?

Comment: It's a default behaviour, rounding up to even; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Comment: Check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036885/round-a-double-in-java/22037280#22037280

Comment: yes I have. public class Test {
 
 

 
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  double d1= 4.55;
  double d2= 17.85;
  DecimalFormat oneDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
  System.out.println(oneDForm.format(d1));
  System.out.println(oneDForm.format(d2));
}
}

Comment: @pujari i believe the information provided in the below answers are valid, but i dont kno y u dint accept any answer, so it might be useful for someone and others dont need to spend time for looking at unanswered questions like this. Y you guys dont understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pujari

Default Rounding mode of  DecimalFormat uses half-even rounding

[According to the document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_EVEN)

"Rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor. Behaves as for ROUND_HALF_UP if the digit to the left of the discarded fraction is odd; behaves as for ROUND_HALF_DOWN if it's even. Note that this is the rounding mode that minimizes cumulative error when applied repeatedly over a sequence of calculations. ."

[this was also mentioned in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144636/rounding-with-decimalformat-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question,

```
double d1= 4.55;
double d2= 17.85;
DecimalFormat oneDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
oneDForm.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP); //You're changing default behavior here
System.out.println(oneDForm.format(d1));
System.out.println(oneDForm.format(d2));
```

you expected output will be : 4.6, 17.9

In my understanding,

You cannot directly roundup`17.85` to `17.9` it is the default behavior, and the rounding up works like this, for even decimals it rounds up to least possible digit

Example if its .05,.25,.45.. it will round to .0,.2,.4 and for odd decimal it is the reverse

I believe [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) one helps to achieve that. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144636/rounding-with-decimalformat-in-java) post is a mere resemblance of your post

Comment: My question is why 17.75 is rounded as 17.8 and 17.85 is also rounded as 17.8.

Comment: bcoz, .7 is odd decimal and .8 is even. If you round 17.95 it results `18.0` not `17.9` since .9 is odd. my answer explains it very well i guess