# DecimalFormat using incorrect RoundingMode even when set explicitly

Tags: java, rounding, decimalformat

Why is this `DecimalFormat` not rounding using `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` as expected, and what should be done to get the expected output? Can it be done with `DecimalFormat`?

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0");

df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

df.format(0.05); // expecting 0.1, getting 0.1
df.format(0.15); // expecting 0.2, getting 0.1  << unexpected

df.format(0.06); // expecting 0.1, getting 0.0  << unexpected
```

I have seen the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10144636/5743988), specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144696/5743988), but it only seems to work when rounding to an integer.

My JDK is 8.0.110 and my JRE is 8.0.730.2

Comment: that _is_ mysterious!

Comment: maybe you'll have to multiply by 10 and divide again as a workaround

Comment: Works fine in 1.7

maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797964/is-inconsistency-in-rounding-between-java-7-and-java-8-a-bug

Comment: interesting discussion here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124448/how-does-java-math-roundingmode-work - that double is not precise

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'm using Java 8. That may be it. I would still like to know how to get the expected output.

Comment: @4castle, I get 0.1 for 0.06 in Java7

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Note that as stated in the answer you linked, the Java 7 behavior you're seeing is *wrong*.

Comment: @user2357112 try this link then https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039915

Comment: While there are explanations for the first two examples, the last example (0.06 giving 0.0) is really unexpected; actually I cannot reproduce it in Java 8.

Comment: @Henry Yeah, I only get `0.0` when I have `HALF_UP` turned on. It's very strange.

Comment: Could that be a locale dependend effect? Which locale are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Answer below using Java 8.)

The issue you are seeing comes from specifying "0.15" or "0.05" in code, which when represented as a double is something slightly less than 0.15. Check this out

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");

df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(0.15);
System.out.println("bd=" + bd);
System.out.println(df.format(0.15)); // expecting 0.1, getting 0.1
bd = new BigDecimal(0.05);
System.out.println("bd=" + bd);
System.out.println(df.format(0.05));
bd = new BigDecimal(0.06);
System.out.println("bd=" + bd);
System.out.println(df.format(0.06));
```

The output of this code is

```
bd=0.1499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375
0.1
bd=0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125
0.1
bd=0.059999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375
0.1
```

A possible solution (if you absolutely need it to round the right way) is to use BigDecimal.valueOf to create the value. For example

```
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.15);
System.out.println("bd=" + bd);
System.out.println(df.format(bd)); // expecting 0.1, getting 0.1
bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.05);
System.out.println("bd=" + bd);
System.out.println(df.format(bd));
bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.06);
System.out.println("bd=" + bd);
System.out.println(df.format(bd));
```

Will now yield

```
bd=0.15
0.2
bd=0.05
0.1
bd=0.06
0.1
```

BTW, as Scary Wombat pointed out, the mask set as 0.0 instead of #.# will make 0.6 0. But I think that was a later edit then when I started looking at it. Use #.#.

Comment: So the problem is `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0");` vs `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat He didn't say so. What are you taking about?

Comment: The problem is writing "0.15" in the code, which is actually not 0.15, it is stored in the system as 0.1499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375

Comment: @EJP Hence my `?` mark.  The OP states using mask of `"0.0"` with a value of 0.06 becomes `0.0` whereas this answer is using a mask or `"#.#"` and the value becomes `0.1`

Comment: I'm getting `"0"` and `"0.0"` from `"#.#"` and `"0.0"` with `0.06`, so I figured they were the same. This answer is very helpful btw. Thanks very much

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, since it includes how to get the expected output, but many thanks to both answers so far for the insight. I'm going to consider the `0.06` thing to be a bug, because I can't reproduce it in other versions either.

Answer (score 4):

When you do

```
df.format(0.15);
```

there are actually *two* rounding operations. The obvious one is the one you asked for with `df.format`, but there's an earlier one that happens at compile time.

The decimal value 0.15 isn't representable as a double. Doubles can only represent rationals whose denominator is a power of two, just like decimal notation can only represent rationals whose denominator is a power of ten. When you write `0.15`, the compiler rounds this to the closest value representable as a double, and that value happens to be

```
0.1499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375
```

which `df.format` correctly rounds down. It's not exactly halfway between 0.1 and 0.2, so the `HALF_UP` rounding mode doesn't matter.

As for

```
df.format(0.06); // expecting 0.1, getting 0.0  << unexpected
```

If you're seeing *that*, that's a bug. It looks like it matches [one linked by ScaryWombat](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039915), reported to be fixed in 8u40 and 8u45. A test on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/ZPJCd7), which uses 8u51, shows the correct behavior. Updating your Java should resolve the issue.

Comment: I like this: "doubles can only represent rationals whose denominator is a power of two"

Comment: Can you then explain `df.format(0.06); // expecting 0.1, getting 0.0  << unexpected` - also why OK for 1.7 and not 1.8?

Comment: @user2357112 Did you you mean to use 0.0… rather than 0.1… after first referring to example of 0.05? Also, superb answer.

Comment: @BasilBourque: Whoops. I meant to use 0.15 instead of 0.05.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) The Wiki article has a good example in the [Rounding rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Rounding_rules)  section. Also you can read section [9.1 of Introduction to Java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/) that expends more about floating point. [BigDecimal](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/math/BigDecimal.java.html) solves most of these short coming by storing the uncalled value inside a BigInteger, the precision and scale in separate in integer fields.